# Get the type of an element in GStreamer

Tags: audio, rust, gstreamer

I'm using the DeviceMonitor in order to get the audio source available in GStreamer.
There are audio sources that I cannot use (I get a "Device is used by another application")

I have a micro plugged and when I print the devices I see there is a `GstPulseDevice`.
Here's the exact output:

```
[Device(ObjectRef { inner: 0x7fad8000cbf0, type: GstPulseDevice }), Device(ObjectRef { inner: 0x7fad7c00de40, type: GstAlsaDevice }), Device(ObjectRef { inner: 0x7fad7c00dd80, type: GstAlsaDevice })]
```

Here's [the crate](https://docs.rs/gstreamer/0.18.8/gstreamer/) I'm using and the code I was using *(until it broke because gstreamer doesn't provide the property `device.bus_path` anymore)*:

```
pub fn get_audio_source() -> Option<Element> {
    let monitor = DeviceMonitor::new();
    monitor.add_filter(Some("Audio/Source"), None);
    monitor.set_show-all(false); // Removing the hidden devices
    monitor.start().unwrap();
    let src = monitor.devices()
        .iter()
        .filter(|device| {
            let bus_path: Result<String, GetError> = device.properties().unwrap().get("device.bus_path");
            return bus_path.is_ok() && bus_path.unwrap() == "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:3:1.2"
        })
        .map(|device| device.create_element(None).unwrap())
        .next();
    if src.is_some() {
        src.as_ref().unwrap().set_property("do-timestamp", true).unwrap();
    }
    monitor.stop();
    return src
}
```

Here's the output when I do `for x in monitor.devices() { dbg!(x.properties()); }`:

```
[src/utils/device_utils.rs:65] x.properties() = Some(
    Structure(
        "pulse-proplist, device.description=(string)\"Monitor\\ of\\ Built-in\\ Audio\\ Digital\\ Stereo\\ \\(HDMI\\ 2\\)\", device.class=(string)monitor, alsa.card=(string)1, alsa.card_name=(string)\"HDA\\ Intel\\ HDMI\", alsa.long_card_name=(string)\"HDA\\ Intel\\ HDMI\\ at\\ 0xf7134000\\ irq\\ 51\", alsa.driver_name=(string)snd_hda_intel, device.bus_path=(string)pci-0000:00:03.0, sysfs.path=(string)/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card1, device.bus=(string)pci, device.vendor.id=(string)8086, device.vendor.name=(string)\"Intel\\ Corporation\", device.product.id=(string)160c, device.product.name=(string)\"Broadwell-U\\ Audio\\ Controller\", device.form_factor=(string)internal, device.string=(string)1, module-udev-detect.discovered=(string)1, device.icon_name=(string)audio-card-pci, is-default=(boolean)true;",
    ),
)
[src/utils/device_utils.rs:65] x.properties() = Some(
    Structure(
        "alsa-proplist, device.api=(string)alsa, device.class=(string)sound, alsa.card=(int)2, alsa.card_name=(string)\"HDA\\ Intel\\ PCH\", alsa.driver_name=(string)HDA-Intel, alsa.name=(string)\"HDA\\ Intel\\ PCH\", alsa.id=(string)PCH, alsa.mixername=(string)\"Realtek\\ ALC283\", alsa.components=(string)\"HDA:10ec0283\\,80862057\\,00100003\";",
    ),
)
[src/utils/device_utils.rs:65] x.properties() = Some(
    Structure(
        "alsa-proplist, device.api=(string)alsa, device.class=(string)sound, alsa.card=(int)0, alsa.card_name=(string)\"OBSBOT\\ Tiny\", alsa.driver_name=(string)USB-Audio, alsa.name=(string)\"OBSBOT\\ Tiny\", alsa.id=(string)Tiny, alsa.mixername=(string)\"USB\\ Mixer\", alsa.components=(string)USB6e30:fef0;",
    ),
)
```

How can I filter that list to keep only the `GstPulseDevice`? How can I check the device type in Rust?

**Edit:** Adding code and crate link
**Edit2:** Adding debug output for the device properties

Comment: can you post an example of the code? Also links to the documentation to the crate you are using would be helpful :)

Comment: I edited my post. I'm not sure it'll help because the code doesn't work. I used to get the audio device using the property `device.bus_path` but for some reason this property does not show anymore. That's why I need to filter using `GstPulseDevice`

Comment: It looks like `device.properties()` returns an `Option<Structure>` that does implement `Debug`. Can you try writing `dbg!(device.properties())` and post what it dumps?

Comment: I modified my post to include the output

Comment: Are you sure PulseAudio is detecting your device? Try running the command `pactl list sources` and comparing its output to that of your previous `dbg!`. If both programs show the same properties you code is correct and the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry for the wait. Right now I'm facing some strange behaviour:
I did the `pactl` command and saw the device. I also saw the `device.bus_path` property.
Then I did `gst-device-monitor-1.0 Audio/Source` which shows me the equivalent but for gstreamer. And I also saw `device.bus_path`.

This is really weird so I checked with my program and now it runs fine. Except for the audio outputs which got a issue related to the device properties changing. I fixed it and in the end it works.
I really don't understand why sometimes the devices don't have all the properties every time

Answer (score 1):

> How can I filter that list to keep only the GstPulseDevice? How can I check the device type in Rust?

As this is your question, you can do that via

```rust
device.type_().name() == "GstPulseDevice"
```

But as the other comment mentioned this is likely not your problem but that PulseAudio does not detect your audio device. In your list there's only the monitor device via PulseAudio, and the actual device only via ALSA directly.

There's some kind of problem with your PulseAudio setup.